# How you can refresh a page in Watir-Webdrive?

Tags: refresh, watir, watir-webdriver

How can I refresh a page using watir-webdrive?
I tried what they are saying here: http://watirwebdriver.com/sending-special-keys/ , but no luck.

```
browser.send_keys :f5
```

Any other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do:

```
browser.refresh
```

See [docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Browser#refresh-instance_method).

Comment: i tried , still get the error: [remote server] file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile201208
31-5896-8q5ft0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.j
s:10198:in `unknown': Modal dialog present (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::Unhandle
dAlertError)         from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir
-webdriver/browser.rb:110:in `refresh'

Comment: The error message is claiming a modal dialog is present. Is there a modal dialog present? If so, you have to close it first. If you manually went to a page with a modal dialog, I do not believe you can refresh the page without closing the dialog first.

Comment: I kill it with this: def callPopupKillerFF
    $pid = Process.create(:app_name => 'ruby clickPopupsFF.rb', :creation_flags => Process::DETACHED_PROCESS).process_id
end

Comment: I have never used that method for closing popups, so not really sure how it works. Do you have a test page that you are having problems refreshing?

Comment: I need refreshing, because when I add something to my cart, the new item isn't automatically put it (refreshed) in my cart. So i need to refresh the page somehow to check if the new item exists in my cart.

Comment: That is fine. As an alternative, you could get the browser's url and navigate there again. Beyond that, unless you can provide a page that reproduces the problem, I do not know how else to help. Sorry.

Comment: I'm glad that this URL isn't dynamic .So i will use your suggestion and ... If you don't mind, can you tell me what you are using to kill javascript pop-up windows?

Comment: Take a look at this page for handling popups http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/.